# Highstocks chart plots wrong data on x-axis when selecting complete interval on the navigator

Tags: highcharts

I got huge set of data.
Its plotting properly. But when I select the graph from min date to max date on the navigator, It returns wrong plot points.
It automatically takes start date from a date before the actual start date.

```
ex: actual start date: 01/01/2008
    resultant start date becomes 31/12/2007
```

Also reduces all the plotting data by some value

```
ex : actual Price as on 01/01/2008 : 1018
     resultant Price as on 31/12/2007 becomes  : 988
```

This issue occurs on highstocks example as well provided on their site.
Check their [example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/)

Comment: Could you provide some screenshots or sample code to show this issue in more detail? The folks from Highcharts routinely monitor Stack Overflow, so that information could help them see whether this truly is a bug. Thank you!

Comment: Is it always showing 1 day before? If so it could be a timezone issue where highcharts is trying to correct for a time change during the year. Without an example I'm not sure about the actual data issue.

Comment: As brightmatrix have written, it would be nice if you will be able to provide screenshots and minimal working example of your issue. Maybe your problem is connected with dataGrouping? http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.dataGrouping